# Not create sample_07 table while Hue Installation

Tags: hadoop, hive, emr, hue

How do I remove the sample tables (sample_07 and sample_08) that being created as part of hue installation (3.7.1)?

Ultimately what i do not want is those tables not to be created. Is there a way for this?

Answer (score 0):

Go to hive and run

```
drop table sample_07;
drop table sample_08;
```

You can do it either from hive interface in Hue or command line.

Comment: Also don't click on installing the Hive Examples in the Hue install wizard